# YARD and RDoc compatibility

Tags: ruby, rdoc, yard

If I document my code with YARD, and use e.g. the `@overload` tag, and someone else installs my gem and it generates the documentation with RDoc, won't the result be messy?

Is there a good way to deal with this?

Comment: Isn't it one way compatible? That is, YARD can read RDoc, but not the other way around. And most people perfer YARD over RDoc.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am getting at. But seeing as people out there might still be using RDoc and not have YARD, how do you cater for that when you use YARD-specific tags to document your code?

Answer (score 0):

Is doesn't support `@overload`, but TomDoc serves as a workable go between. RDoc now supports TomDoc out of the box, and Yard has yard-tomdoc plugin. YARD is still better (IMO) for large projects, but for small libraries or tools TomDoc works well and can be used by both systems.